# How to handle data included \n without entering a new cell for CSV in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to handle data that include `\n` to be written in csv file, but I don't want it to enter in a new cell column

```
import csv

with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w+') as employee_file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',')

    employee_writer.writerow(['John Smith', 'Accounting', 'November'])
    employee_writer.writerow(['Erica Meyers\nEnter new line??', 'IT New Line', 'March'])
```

Currently, the application writes data that include `\n` to the csv as a new cell like this

[image: Current Output]

This I wish handle data `\n` by entering it into new line within the same cell A:2 like this

[image: What I want to handle \n data]

This `\n` was produced by user pressing enter key while they was inputting data.

Since my application is a rich text input from user, how can I handle this kind of data without breaking a new cell? Thanks

Comment: How would you like to print when `\n` is present?

Comment: @RafaelC I would like it just enter a new line within the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module already handles this for you, quoting the field to prevent the newline from being interpreted as a record separator.

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting quote around '\n' like this `employee_writer.writerow(["Erica Meyers'\n'Enter new line??', 'IT New Line", 'March'])`, but still it enter a new cell.

Comment: @HouyNarun: You don't have to do/add anything. It quotes it for you. You're going to have to be more specific about what you mean by "new cell", because the Excel should match the quoting of the `csv` module's default dialect.

Comment: I added image to show this desire result. Thank you very much

Comment: @HouyNarun: Is this in Excel, or some other spreadsheet program? Also, just noticed, but in Python 2, the output file should be opened in binary mode (`"wb"`, not `"w+"`; if you need to both read and write it, `"w+b"`).

Comment: It is Libre Office Cal program for Ubuntu OS, it is very much like excel in Ms Office for windows.

Comment: I’ve also open it with any text editor, it also show new line and comma separated as defined in delimiter, what’s supposed to do next? Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun: Take a look at the `csv` module docs. There are different quoting rules by OS, and odds are you want the [unix dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.unix_dialect). It's also possible Libre Office has it's own weird quoting rules; you'd have to look them up.

Comment: thanks so much I’ll look at them and back to let you know :)